# jQuery masked input plugin not working on smartphone

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, smartphone, maskedinput

I have been using the masked input plugin for jQuery for a long time.

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

I never had any issues with the plugin until yesterday I got a support ticket regarding the plugin behaving erratically on the Driod phone.

e.g.
When the user tries to enter the phone number (123)345-9646 in the phone number on the demo tab, it comes out (321)345-4696 or something like that.

I do not own a smartphone therefore I cannot really test.

I'm not sure what my best approach is solving this problem. Are there known issues for this plugin on a smartphone?

Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442481/masked-input-not-working-in-android-mobiles/29437478#29437478

Answer (score 1):

I hit this issue as well.  Only happens on Droid.  I looked at jquerymobile.com to see if that framework does any browser detection but it doesn't  There was another jquery I found that purports to do browser detection but its failed my initial tests.

I was going down the route of just turning masked input off if it was a droid.  I don't like it, but its the only option I can think of without setting up some kind of specific testing environment.

Anyway our mobile user base is really small right now.

Comment: Yes that's the solution I ended up as well.