# masked input not working in android mobiles?

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-plugins, maskedtextbox

I am using the [digitalbush masked input jQuery plugin](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput). It is working fine in web browsers and the iPhone browser perfectly, but it is not working for Android mobile devices.

My issue :
mask is
in input field **_ - _** - ___.

When I type numbers it will 12345685555___-***-***

Example: http://rossbender.com/temp/mask.html

Any suggestions? How can I solve this?

Thanks
Prasad.

Comment: can you share the DOM you have used ?

Comment: $('input[name="user[ssn]"]').mask("999-99-9999"); but all masks are returns same behaviour.

Comment: i mean the html you have used?

Comment: Ruby on rails (html view page)

Comment: please share the html code?

Comment: <input type="tel" id="socialsecurity" name="user[ssn]" />           The demo site also not working in android mobiles http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin

Comment: Have you used maxlength attribute?

Comment: no, because ssn field is fixed length.

Comment: This was fixed awhile ago (11 months ago) but for some reason the distribution posted on the website never took the changes. If you grab from the raw source, the fix works: https://raw.github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/master/src/jquery.maskedinput.js

Comment: @JonathanRowny Can you make an answer from your comment? Because in fact, it solves the problem.

Comment: @DurgaPrasad My answer appears to be working for most people. Do you mind marking it the accepted answer?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I resolved this issue with three actions, which have fixed this for all Android 4.0+ phones:

1. Update masked-input to at least version **1.4**
2. Add `type="tel"` to the input, to trigger the numeric keyboard
3. Remove the input's `maxlength` attribute or set it to a value certain not to interfere with the caret action, like `20`.

Comment: Worked for me on android 4.x

Comment: worked for me on 5.1.1, using input mask on angular form using angular-payments. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me. Samsung keyboard has an issue because of predictive text, which was resolved by forcing numeric keyboard.

Comment: Worked for me on android 6.0.1, Note 7

Comment: @Max - did you already have a recent version of masked-input, and was the `maxlength` value set?

Comment: This didn't work for my application, noticed Masked Input wasn't being maintained anymore so I found a new library: http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/
Similar basic call and works like a charm!

Comment: Solved by adding type="tel"... thanks!!!

Comment: Obrigado amigo, me salvou! Funcionou perfeitamente!!

Answer (score 8):

I tried using the raw script that Jonathan Rowny mentioned, but I was still having the same problem on an S3 - Chrome browser. I think it has something to do with inputs `type="tel"` and/or `type="number"`. I ended up having to use another plugin. http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

**jquery-mask** (not to be confused with *jquery-masked-input*) is very similar but the syntax was slightly different. Hope this helps anyone else with this issue.

jquery-masked-input syntax:
`$("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");`

VS

jquery-mask syntax: `('#phone').mask('(000) 000-0000');`

Comment: The raw script Jonathan Rowny mentioned doesn't work for me either on Android 4.1 + Chrome.  I tried Igor Escobar's script (jquery-mask) that's mentioned above and it worked perfectly!

Comment: Igor Escobar's script doesn't work on older Android stock browsers though

Answer (score 3):

This was fixed awhile ago but for some reason the distribution posted on the website never took the changes. If you grab from the raw source, the fix works: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/master/src/jquery.maskedinput.js

Comment: i have used above .Js file. still problem is not solved. i am using Android jelly bean Os and Chtome/Firefox browser

Comment: @user2788596 maybe it's because of the cache of your browser. Anyway, today it works and it's 1.4.1 version that you can get here https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/tree/master/dist

Answer (score 3):

After trying different mask libraries (Inputmask, ui-mask, ngMask) I ended up using  [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/ which works pretty well and is also lightweight and well documented and has angularjs, react ,... samples.

Answer (score 1):

To further enhance the accepted answer of Tony Brasunas, add following snippet in jquery.maskedinput.js for point number 3 to dynamically increase maxlength so it doesn't interfere with caret action.

*Remove the input's maxlength attribute or set it to a value certain not to interfere with the caret action, like 20.*

```
    defs = $.mask.definitions;
    tests = [];
    partialPosition = len = mask.length;
    firstNonMaskPos = null;

    //insert snippet below
    if (chrome && android) {
        console.log("chrome && android");
        var allAllowedRegExps = '';
        jQuery.each(defs, function (key, value) {
            allAllowedRegExps = allAllowedRegExps + key;
        });
        allAllowedRegExps = allAllowedRegExps.replace(/\[/g, '');
        allAllowedRegExps = allAllowedRegExps.replace(/\]/g, '');
        allAllowedRegExps = '[^' + allAllowedRegExps + ']';
        var re = new RegExp(allAllowedRegExps, "g");
        var actual = mask;
        var replacedVal = actual.replace(re, "");
        var actualValue = actual.length - replacedVal.length;
        if ($(this).attr('maxlength') !== undefined) {
            $(this).attr('maxlength', parseInt(this.attr('maxlength')) + parseInt(actualValue));
        }
   }

    mask = String(mask);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem and resolved it by removing the attribute **type="number"** from the asp textbox.  After that masked input worked even on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

The library used in the question is no longer being maintained. I switched my application to [jQuery Mask Input](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) as it works great, has a very similar base init call to the former library making for an extremely easy transition and, at the time of this post, [jQuery Mask Input](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) is regularly maintained at GitHub.

My issue was with the phone number masker moving the cursor back to the second position when 3 or 4 digits were entered. The cursor continued to act odd after that point. The problem was noticed using jQuery Masked Input v1.4.1 (old library) in android tablets using Chrome post major version 51.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a quick fix:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
var isAndroid = /Android/i.test(ua);
var isChrome = /Chrome/i.test(ua);

// Fix masking on Chrome for mobile devices
if (isAndroid && isChrome) {
    $('.price_input').attr('type','tel');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by using 1.4.1 and setting the max length to one plus the number of chars in the mask.  The mask limited the actual input and the max length +1 fixed the problem of not being able to type numbers in the field.