# Masked input is not working in android phones

Tags: jquery, maskedinput

Hi I have used the masked input plugin [click](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) for my website to format the phone number which is entered by the user I am using the format as `(123) 456-7890` its working fine with PC's but when I browse the site with android devices and enter the phone number as `1234567890` its order is getting changed as `(213) 456-7890` or any random order automatically.

You can see this issue in their demo site itself here is the [link](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)
In the goto demo tab next to usage tab.

can anyone suggest me a solution for the same.

Comment: Do you have a link to your site?

Comment: You can see this issue in their site itself demo http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: I've tested this on an android device and I'm not getting any issues. Makeu sure you're using verion 1.3.1 as it fixes issues with android devices. http://digitalbush.com/2013/01/21/masked-input-1-3-1/

Comment: I have used the 1.3.1 version itself but still I see the problem

Comment: The demo does not work on Samsung Galaxy S4 (Android 4.3, WebKit 537.36).

Comment: Also using a Galaxy S4 and the demo no longer works.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442481/masked-input-not-working-in-android-mobiles/29437478#29437478

Answer (score 9):

I resolved this issue with three actions, which have fixed this for all Android 4.0+ phones:

1. Update masked-input to at least version **1.4**
2. Add `type="tel"` to the input, to trigger the phone keypad
3. Remove the input's `maxlength` attribute or set it to a value certain not to interfere with the caret action, like `20`.

Comment: I was having some issues with masked dates. Updating masked-input and setting the input type to date solved my problem too.

Comment: Setting it to "date" did not solve it for me. Even though i'm using a mask for a date, I had to set it to type="tel"

Comment: Thanks! Doing only the first two was necessary for me on a bootstrap 3+ form-control

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the original answer (in comment) by [Jonathan Rowny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/490498/jonathan-rowny) on "[masked input not working in android mobiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442481/masked-input-not-working-in-android-mobiles)":

> This was fixed awhile ago (11 months ago) but for some reason the
>   distribution posted on the website never took the changes. If you grab
>   from the raw source, the fix works:
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/master/src/jquery.maskedinput.js

Comment: 2015, abril, 13, yeah, it fixes my problem with a lot of mobile browsers.

Comment: It didn't help me. Actually it created other problems :(

Answer (score -5):

```
<script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" type="text/javascript">http://    digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> //input mask
jQuery(function($){
    $(".date").mask("99/99/9999");
    $(".phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
    $(".zip").mask("99999");
    $(".year").mask("9999");
    //,{placeholder:" "}
    });
</script>

html

<input class="phone" id = "aligned-phone" type="tel" name="phone" value="<%=phone %>"   Placeholder = "Cell Phone" autocomplete="<%= autofill%>">
```

i find that using class works the best...
Good luck

Comment: The question is about "my code DOES work on PC but DOES NOT work on mobile". He is not asking about best mask formula, your don't answer the question.