# How to set masked input to edittext in android?

Tags: java, android, maskedinput

Suppose i want to set masked input with 20 characters
Example : 12345-12345-12345-12345
How can I do it there are only examples given for phone numbers masked input, iam new to android please help

Comment: Have you tried using https://github.com/toshikurauchi/MaskedEditText ? This is what you want ... :)

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442481/masked-input-not-working-in-android-mobiles

Comment: Thanks Haresh Chhelana and Anoop